# Вапыкательница — кто это?

Tags: выбор-слов, словообразование, значение-слов, окказионализмы

*— (…) Погодите минуту, — геолог принес старую книгу, нашел нужную страницу и прочитал: — «Женщина есть ехидна, и скорпион, и лев, и медведь, и василиск, и
аспид, и похоть несытая, и неправдам кузнец, и грехам пастух, и
**вапыкательница**. Скачет, пляшет, хребтом вихляет, бедрами трясет, головой кивает...» (…)

— Постой, Леонид, ты прочел какое-то мудреное слово!

— Вапыкательница? **От слова «вап» — краска.** Иначе говоря, **накрашенная.***
[И. Ефремов. Лезвие бритвы](https://books.google.ee/books?id=LbHMAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT201&lpg=PT201&dq=%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0&source=bl&ots=NSipulnW5U&sig=NLEYGUeFF1XB7aNJWBvqi1KC_ZI&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjCsfnGjevfAhUKCywKHXC1CtoQ6AEwAnoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0&f=false)

Нашла объяснение в [Большом вопросе](http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/15897-pomozhete-uznat-znachenie-slova-vapykatelnica.html): "Накрашенная, до неприличия, женщина. Иногда модница" [пункт. авт. — Р. М.]. Оно меня не убедило.

Читать — читательница, писать — писательница, искать — искательница.
Каким же должен быть глагол, от которого это интересное слово образовано?
Правильна ли авторская формулировка, как вы считаете?
И видится ли вам какое-либо другое значение этого слова?

Answer (score 2):

Модница - вряд ли.  Есть такое слово, и глагол есть - вапить.

У Даля "вапить" - красить:

ВАПНА ж. новорос. ваnно ср. стар. известь, известка. Вап м. ваna ж. всякое красильное вещество, краска. | Костр. красный карандаш. | Арх. от вопить, крик, рев, зов. Экой вап подняли. Где вообще акают, произносят однако воп, вопль; где окают, вап. Вапить что, стар. красить; расписывать красками; новорос. белить известкой стены. Ваповый, вапный стар. относящийся к извести или краске. Ваплюха об. вологодск. чумичка, замарашка, особ. грязная, неопрятная женщина, стряпуха. http://slovardalya.ru/description/vapna/2571

Перевод слова "вап"с коми - краска. На Академике есть словарь иностранных языков. Там вапöн мичöдны дöра — окрасить холст краской

ВАП, ВАПА [< гр. окрашивание] – 1) состав, содержащий медные соли; служит для предохранения, т. наз. резервирования, набитых мест ткани от окрашивания в синий цвет при погружении её в индиго; 2) жидкая малярная краска для стен; 3) раствор извести для заливки камня при постройке; 4) полые цилиндры на самолётах для перевозки жидких или газообразных материалов (Большой словарь иностранных слов.- Издательство «ИДДК», 2007.)
https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_fwords/49985/%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BF

У Ефремова, видимо, используется в значении **"одержимая"** - шаманка у северных народностей, которая мажет лицо белой краской перед тем, как войти в транс: "Скачет, пляшет, хребтом вихляет, бедрами трясет, головой кивает..." - похожий образ, его представление о женщине как одержимой - только красится, поёт, пляшет.